# how can i make laravel api show by string value

Tags: laravel, api

trying to build an API for a payment script. but I want to use API to show by $merchant_id or $reference number. But when I try to get with json, only returns by $id which is the primary key.

How can I make it show by $merchant_id which is a string?

here is the code in UserController

```
public function show($merchant_key)
{
    return Exttransfer::find($merchant_key);
    
 
}
```

and the code in App/Api

```
Route::get('Exttransfer/{$merchant_key}', 'UserController@show');
```

No matter what I do it only show by $id
An example of a merchant_key is ) OBGDTE36B2

Comment: Can you show model of Exttransfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `find()` retrieves model by its primary key, so Laravel considers `$merchant_key` as id.
Try this

From:

```
public function show($merchant_key)
{
    return Exttransfer::find($merchant_key);
}
```

To :

```
public function show($merchant_key)
{
    return Exttransfer::where('merchant_key',$merchant_key)->get();
}
```

**If you want to get single record use `first()` instead of `get()`.**

[Read More about find()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-find)

Comment: It shows up now only if I use the route `Route::resource('Exttransfer', 'UserController');` instead of  `Route::get('Exttransfer/{$merchant_key}', 'UserController@show');`. How can I get to return base on $merchant_key and $referencenumber , instead of just $merchant_key

Comment: I would strongly recommend on using `first()` instead of `get()`

Answer (score 0):

According to eloquent documentation:

#find($key)

> The find method returns the model that has a primary key matching the given key. If $key is a model instance, find will attempt
> to return a model matching the primary key. If $key is an array of
> keys, find will return all models which have a primary key in the
> given array

So you should use something like `return Exttransfer::where('merchant_key', $merchant_key)->first();`